# Geolocation Auto Refresh Page

Tags: javascript, maps

I want to take geolocation data of the user's current location but when the page is auto refreshed it won't work. Please help me to solve this. my current code sections are included in belove.

1. Auto Refesh & Doesn't Works

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <h1 class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">MAPS</h1>
    <div class="container" id="map" style="height: 500px; width:100%"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

2. No Refresh & Works

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">MAPS</h1>
  <div class="container" id="map" style="height: 500px; width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

javascript code

```js
let map, infoWindow;

function initMap() {
  map = new
  
  google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 6,
  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  const locationButton = document.createElement("button");
  locationButton.textContent = "Pan to Current Location";
  locationButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(locationButton);

  locationButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          const pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          };
          
          infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
          infoWindow.setContent("Location found.");
          infoWindow.open(map);
          map.setCenter(pos);
        },
        () => {
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  });
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(
    browserHasGeolocation ?
    "Error: The Geolocation service failed." :
    "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation.");
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give exact latitude or longitude.

```
<input type="hidden" id="lat" value="-34.397"/>
<input type="hidden" id="long" value="150.644"/>
```

you have to call the function init on window load.

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  function initMap();
};
```

now you to get the value of hidden inputs in that function like this

```
> let map, infoWindow;
> let latitude=document.getElementById('lat').value;
> let long=document.getElementById('long').value;
> function initMap() {   map = new
> google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
>     center: { lat: latitude, lng: long },
>     zoom: 6,   });   infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();   const locationButton = document.createElement("button");  
> locationButton.textContent = "Pan to Current Location";  
> locationButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");  
> map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(locationButton);
> locationButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
>     // Try HTML5 geolocation.
>     if (navigator.geolocation) {
>       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
>         (position) => {
>           const pos = {
>             lat: position.coords.latitude,
>             lng: position.coords.longitude,
>           };
>           infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
>           infoWindow.setContent("Location found.");
>           infoWindow.open(map);
>           map.setCenter(pos);
>         },
>         () => {
>           handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
>         }
>       );
>     } else {
>       // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
>       handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
>     }   }); }
> 
> function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
> infoWindow.setPosition(pos);   infoWindow.setContent(
>     browserHasGeolocation
>       ? "Error: The Geolocation service failed."
>       : "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation."   );   infoWindow.open(map); }
```

i hope this will work